# Error occur after upgrading MySql from 5.1 to 5.6.10 while restore the dump file

Tags: mysql

**Error 1728 at line 3 :cannot load from mysql.proc the table is corrupted**

That Error appears after upgrading the MySql version. I am upgrading From 5.1 to 5.6.10. 
The error appears when I try to restore the dump file.

Answer (score 4):

Run [`mysql_upgrade`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html). AFAIK, this is a standard MySQL upgrade step.

From MySQL 5.6 [upgrade instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html):

> After upgrading to a new version of MySQL, run mysql_upgrade (see
>   Section 4.4.7, “mysql_upgrade — Check and Upgrade MySQL Tables”). This
>   program checks your tables, and attempts to repair them if necessary.
>   It also updates your grant tables to make sure that they have the
>   current structure so that you can take advantage of any new
>   capabilities. (Some releases of MySQL introduce changes to the
>   structure of the grant tables to add new privileges or features.)