# Copying raw mysql files to Windows 7 MySQL 5.6 obtained via mysqlhotcopy from Linux MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, workbench

Assuming I only have access to the raw files (.myd, .myi, .frm), would I simply copy+paste mysql db files obtained from "/var/lib/mysql/mydb" to "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47\data\mydb" or is it "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mydb"? I was using mysql-5.1.43 on Linux and now mysql 5.6 on Windows 7. I don't have access to the Linux anymore.

I have tried the top 2 Windows locations with no success. I cannot even tell where data is actually being kept when I create a new schema in Workbench; neither of the two locations have the actual data files for the new dummy schema I create, even after I post some data to the tables.

I don't seem to get any direct answer to my question on similar questions asked on this site.

Kindly help.

Comment: Using `mysql> select @@datadir\G` found the actual data path. Shut down `MySQL56` service; copied mydb folder whole to the path. Resumed the service and everything now works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can move the raw files to the Server directory.

Check the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini for the **datadir** entry as this is the location the server will use/look for.

Don't forget to upgrade your tables as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14934258/2274885).

Comment: There is actually no my.ini at "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6". There is only "my-default.ini" whose uncommented content is as below.

`[mysqld]' and `
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'

Comment: have you created a server instance? more information on your setup would be useful...